# Multi-Line Placeholder Text in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui, placeholder

I'm using the Material UI for a React App I'm developing.

I'm using the `TextField` component and I need a multi-line placeholder for a textarea. I currently have:

```
       <TextField
            id="details"
            fullWidth={true}
            multiline={true}
            rows={5}
            label="Give us some additional details:"
            placeholder="- Tell us about this project \n - What skills are you looking for ? &#10; - What tools do you need an expert in? &#10; - What is your timeline?"
        />
```

It needs to appear as:

```
- Tell us about this project 
- What skills are you looking for ?
- What tools do you need an expert in? 
- What is your timeline?
```

You can see I've tried `&#10;` as well as `\n` to no avail. any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use simple place holder shrink enabled :

here is the working codesandbox :[Multiline Placeholder](https://codesandbox.io/s/z354lwp3r4)

Comment: This does not work with Safari

Comment: Does not work in Chrome either